# getting attribute using jquery $(this)

Tags: jquery, attributes, this

How can I get the attribute ID from the button? It returns undefined. I ask this because I will have many buttons with different ID like: edit-user-21 or edit-user-22

```js
    function edituser() {
     var test = $(this).attr('id');
      alert(test);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-primary" id="btn-edit-2" onclick="edituser()">Edit</button>
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".btn-primary").click(function () {
         alert($(this).attr("id"));

     });
 });

Answer (score 1):

Try this... when clicking on the button

```
<button class="btn-primary" id="btn-edit-2" onclick="edituser(this)">Edit</button>
```

and function will be

```
 function edituser(this) {
    var test = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can access to the element by Id

```
$('#ID')
```

It should looks like this:

```
var myButtonId = $('#btn-edit-2')
```

Comment: But I'm populating multiple buttons with many different IDs. That's why I wanna know how to grab the ID by using the $(this) selector.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function edituser() {
     var test = $(this.id);
      alert(test);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-primary" id="btn-edit-2" onclick="edituser()">Edit</button>
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```